# Replacing speakers' transformer

Tags: power-supply, transformer, speakers

I have recently purchases new speakers and I have noticed a slight hum coming from the transformer, therefore I am considering replacing it. The transformer, used to power an internal amplifier, specifications are as follows: 230V~50Hz - 13.5V~3.5A. However I'am having trouble finding a replacement with exact same specifications.

The wattage of the current transformer is 13.5V * 3.5A = 47.25W, could I use another 50W transformer with different voltage specifications without risking to blow up my speakers?

Let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: Before you buy anything, check that the transformer is properly bolted down, or not vibrating against a metal plate, etc. A loose device could cause hum.

Comment: @DaveTweed: this is more a question about how to get a non-standard voltage rather than about specifying a power supply.

Comment: @DwayneReid: I disagree. The way the question is worded, it appears that the OP thinks that any 50W transformer would do. The linked question explains how voltage and current are independently relevant. Also, it isn't clear whether we're talking literally about a transformer, or more generically about a plug-in power supply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly the easiest way to match your transformer is to obtain a toroidal transformer 12 Vac, 50 Watt, then add an extra winding over top of the existing windings. You will need to experiment to find out how many turns are needed.

Choose wire size to handle 4 Amps.

Then connect this new winding in series with the existing 12V winding coming from the transformer.

You may have to swap the ends of the extra winding so that the voltage adds instead of subtracts to the original secondary.

The first time that you do this will take a bit of time but the next one will go quickly.